# How can I best isolate a particular program (game)

Tags: windows-10, security

I have a game I'd like to play; it's widely used, however it has a custom installer with which I am not totally comfortable.

I'd like to isolate the program from the rest of my PC, and from other devices on my LAN.

I was thinking about:

1. creating a VLAN that isolates my PC from the rest of the devices
2. using a separate HD that contains only the OS and the game, and then physically swapping the cables to the motherboard when I wanted to play that game

Are there other steps I should take, or are there issues with these steps?

Answer (score 0):

You could install and isolate this application in a sandbox,
using a product such as the free
[Sandboxie](https://github.com/sandboxie-plus/sandboxie).

Putting that application in a sandbox will ensure that it can only modify
files inside the sandbox, although it can still read all files.
Other computers on the LAN will not be able to access the sandbox,
so cannot run the game (don't share the folder `C:\Sandbox` if you don't
want them to see it at all).

This will also simplify the clean uninstallation of the game by just deleting
the contents of the sandbox.

You need to set the internet restriction on the sandbox to allow or disallow
internet access, as required for the game.
You can use the menu of *Configure > Windows Shell Integration*
to set up an icon on the desktop to run the game withing the sandbox.